# Navier Stokes runge kutta question

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, runge-kutta-methods

I was playing a little bit with the Runge-Kutta procedure for the Incompressible Navier-Stokes equation and came up with something strange, so I would like to know where I'm wrong or doing something I shouldn't.

Let's consider
$u_i = u^n + \Delta t \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}F(u_j)u_j - c_i \Delta t G \phi_i $

where $F$ is the right hand side operator of the Navier-Stokes equation and $G$ is the discrete gradient operator.

So if I want to find a pressure equation, I should apply the divergence $M$ operator both sides

$Mu_i = Mu^n + \Delta t \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}MF(u_j)u_j - c_i \Delta t MG \phi_i $

and by employing the incompressibility constraint in the inner stages and of course for the $u^n$ (i.e. $M u^n = 0$ and $Mu_i = 0$), I get

$ MG \phi_i = \frac{1}{c_i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}MF(u_j)u_j$

Let's define $L = MG$ as the discrete laplacian operator, so that

$ L \phi_i = \frac{1}{c_i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}MF(u_j)u_j$

I know that if I solve this pressure poisson equation, I would get the $\phi_i$ lagrange multiplier that allows me to project the velocity into a divergence free field.

But since I need the gradient of the pseudo-pressure, what if I write something like

$ \phi_i = \frac{1}{c_i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}L^{-1}MF(u_j)u_j$

$ G\phi_i = \frac{1}{c_i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}GL^{-1}MF(u_j)u_j$

but

$GL^{-1}M = G(MG)^{-1}M = GG^{-1}M^{-1}M = I$

so I get that

$G\phi_i = \frac{1}{c_i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}a_{ij}F(u_j)u_j$

that implies that $u_i = u_n$, hence I'm not advancing in time ?? I don't know where am I wrong. Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: You have a mix of equations that have derivatives in $t$ and some conservation equations that do not have them. This is usually called a DAE system. You need DAE techniques to transform it consistently into an ODE system. In the case of linear equations in the non-differential (algebraic) part you can select grid points that get eliminated by them so that the ODE system has as many state variables as differential equations.

Comment: This is of course just a general idea, people that have done since times of old have developed more systematic approaches that actually use the structure of the PDE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that this is a DAE of index 2, but numerically rather than solving the ODE equivalent system, it is better to solve

Comment: Index 1 one can still treat naively, index 3 needs very careful treatment, index 2 is in-between, simple ideas carefully executed can still work. So a simple application of RK4 can lead to a rapid decomposition of the solution.

Comment: Sorry half ansewer got deleted, it wasn't the full answer I wanted to write. What I meant is that the Navier-Stokes equation with a runge kutta procedure are usually solved as I posted, but playing aroundthe equation I found an absurd that starts from I wrote in the main post: "But since I need the gradient ...". I was wondering if I can write $L^{-1} =(MG)^{-1}$ maybe that's the thing I'm not allowed to do. Anyway the procedure I followed is presented in many papers recently: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0021999111006838

Comment: Please insert relevant information like links and further motivation and insights directly into the question text. Comments usually should serve to highlight such perceived shortcomings, not to accumulate information.